# Why does Typescript append numbers to my variables in generated JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using typescriptlang.org's Typescript editor to generate some Javascript for an existing project. So this may be specific to that site. But I am getting a strange result with certain variable names. I have checked the list of reserved words and don't see them anywhere. In this specific case the variable names are "left" and "right". In JS they end up as as "left_1" and "right_1". If I replace them with "left" and "right" in JS, there seem to be no ill effects. Perhaps these are future reserved words?

Here's the Tyepscript:

```js
let left = { index: 4, get page(): number { return this.index; } };
let right = {
 offset: 4,
 get index(): number { return maxPageNumber - this.offset },
 get page(): number { return pageCount - this.offset }
};
let center = {
 get offset(): number {
  // relative to the halfway point between beginning and ending pages
  return this.index
   ? pageNumber.compare(Math.floor(pageCount / 2))
   : 0;
 },
 get index(): number {
  return pageNumber.between(left.page + 1, right.page - 1)
   ? 4
   : 0;
 },
 get page(): number { return pageNumber + this.offset; }
};
```

And here's the Javascript:

```js
var left_1 = { index: 4, get page() { return this.index; } };
var right_1 = {
 offset: 4,
 get index() { return maxPageNumber - this.offset; },
 get page() { return pageCount - this.offset; }
};
var center = {
 get offset() {
  // relative to the halfway point between beginning and ending pages
  return this.index
   ? pageNumber.compare(Math.floor(pageCount / 2))
   : 0;
 },
 get index() {
  return pageNumber.between(left_1.page + 1, right_1.page - 1)
   ? 4
   : 0;
 },
 get page() { return pageNumber + this.offset; }
};
```

Comment: You probably have the variable with the same name somewhere else in the code. Not reproducible on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: Hmmmm.... You are right. I have tried pasting just that block and then the whole class into another instance of playground and it did not modify the names. There are other classes in the original playground session but none have left or right variables defined. Nonetheless, you have prompted me in the right direction for finding the scenario that tips it over. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's converting block-scope `let`s do function-scope `var`s, the transpiler needs to make sure the variable names are unique in the function if it's going to replicate the desired behavior using ES5 code. So most likely there's some other `left` and `right` variable in the surrounding function, and so the transpiler is renaming the variables to avoid a collision.

Comment: A collision was my first thought. But there are no other variables called left or right in that entire file. Also, I had renamed them to leftGroup and rightGroup. It did the same thing -- renamed them both with the number. There is also a "center" variable used in the same way in the same scope scenario. And it does not get modified.